# Python: read list of numbers, convert from string back to individual numbers

Tags: python, io, type-conversion

If I'm reading a list of numbers from a text file `5 12 8 11 7 4 3 5 5 3 2 1`, they'll get processed as a string. My guess is as one string like `"5 12 8 11 7 4 3 5 5 3 2 1"`?

How do convert `"5 12 8 11 7 4 3 5 5 3 2 1"` to `[5, 12, 8, 11, 7, 4, 3, 5, 5, 3, 2, 1]` so i can run them through a function.

Comment: Try this out:
sList = "5 12 8 11 7 4 3 5 5 3 2 1"
numbers = sList.split(" ")
result = map(lambda number: int(number), numbers) #it's not a safe cast. Sounds better if you use a conversion inside a try/catch statement.
print(list(result))

Answer (score 1):

It is an easy question:

```
>>>numbers_str = "5 12 8 11 7 4 3 5 5 3 2 1"
>>>numbers_int = [int(i) for i in numbers_str.split()]
>>>numbers_int
[5, 12, 8, 11, 7, 4, 3, 5, 5, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: yep, this is the way